# Win 10 will not disable hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate

I am trying to **get rid of the hiberfil.sys file**, with no luck.

I tried turning off hibernation in the Settings, with [this guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/delete-hiberfilsys-by-disabling-windows-hibernate-function/)

Turning off *"Allow hybrid sleep"* did not change anything. Windows doesn't remove the file, and I am not allowed to remove the file.

Typing the `powercfg.exe -h off` command also did not change anything. I get an error, Windows doesn't remove the file, and I am not allowed to remove the file.

```
C:\Users\Cogni>powercfg.exe -h off

Unable to perform operation.  An unexpected error (0x65b) has
occurred:  Function failed during execution.
```

I tried restarting the computer, still nothing works.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Based on my research you will only get that error if you attempt to run the command in a non-elevated command prompt as a user who isn't an Administrator

Answer (score 6):

Hibernating needs to be off, and only an administrator can change that setting. Then you need to restart to remove the OS's lock on the file, and after the restart, the file is gone.

Answer (score 4):

Right click Command Prompt and then click Run as administrator.
Or we could disable it through Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings\Change advanced power settings:

[image: Disable Hinbernation]

Comment: Such option is unavailable in my computer's Power Options. Why?

Comment: @Incognito I think hybrid sleep is a different thing. It's only available on desktop computers and is a combination of Sleep and Hibernation

Answer (score 2):

In most cases the actual reason of `Unable to perform operation [...] Function failed during execution` error is that being member of Administrators group is not enough. You have to **intentionally** run Command Prompt as Administrator.

When searching for "Command Prompt" from Start menu, select "**Run as administrator**" from the right side options. Click on it and when terminal window pops up - you should be able to see "**Administrator**: Command Prompt" in the window's title bar.

[image]

Enter the `powercfg.exe -h off` command again - now it should turn the hibernation off without 0x65b error.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late I know but if you are wondering:

Open a command prompt as an admin and type `powercfg /h on`

And if you want to revert back: `powercfg /h off`

Comment: The question itself contains the command ```powercfg.exe -h off```, and the two-year-old answer states that it must be done with administrator privileges,  so this doesn’t add any information.

Comment: But the two-year old answer could be better formatted. It's easy to miss the fact that Joy specifically addresses the need to run cmd.exe as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Control Panel`.
2. Search for `power` and open `Power Options`.
3. Click on `change plan settings`
4. Click on `Change advanced power settings`.
5. Scroll down to `Sleep` and disable `Allow Hybrid Sleep`.
6. Scroll down further to `Battery` and in `Critical Battery Action` put `On Battery` and `Plugged in` to sleep or something other than `Hibernate`.
7. Open CMD as administrator and type `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` and hit enter.
8. Now restart and hibernation file will be gone and some extra space on C drive will be available (3.1 GB in my case).