# How do I purge the content of the Win7 Hibernate system file

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I hibernate my Win7 Pro laptop every night.  The  c:\hiberfil.sys  now is nearly 13 GBytes.  I would like to delete it so that a new (hopefully smaller file) is created tonight.  It is locked while Windows is running. How can I delete / purge it short of re-booting the laptop in DOS mode (assuming I can do it from there).

Similar sort of issue with the swap file (c:\pagefile.sys --> 16 GB)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disable hibernation, reboot, then enable it again.  However, the size, is going to be the same size.  Likewise the same story is true with the page file.  You should submit an answer in either case

Comment: @Ramhound - thanks for tips. ....

I'm only using 7 GB of memory, why is the hibernate file 13 GB?
I hibernate using the shutdown menu. Not sure what you mean "disable it".

Comment: You can disable your ability to hibernate then after you reboot enable it again

Comment: So in other words, just reboot.
I might as well boot in Dos mode then.
OK - will try that the next time.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1203061/win-10-will-not-disable-hibernate) answers explains how to enable or disable hibernation on any version of Windows.  Windows 7 doesn’t have a “DOS mode”, Windows has been running on the NT kernel, since Windows XP.

Comment: But it could take a week or two, or until the damn windows reminders to reboot after a windows update wear me down to the point I cannot take them anymore  :-(

Comment: OK - I'll try Safe Mode and try delete it from the DOS command prompt then

Comment: Thanks - I've browsed through the discussion at This answers ...

I will try one or more of the suggestions there.

However what struck me was the realisation that then I won't be able to hibernate the laptop every night (as it really is disabled). If what you say is true, the file will still be re-created at size 13 GB, so that defeats the object (to recover as much as possible of that 13 GB disk space.)

There was a sneaky workaround, to move some files from my D: partition so that there is no longer 13 GB free space on the C: partition. I just love that solution, it's a real

Comment: {{ Deleted by Mokubai 18 hours ago }}

Comment: to Windows (which you can see I am not particularly keen on).

I will post what works below when I next reboot the laptop (so don't hold your breath for that).